# Are propositions uniquely determined by their non-equivalent implications?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I was reading up on Pragmatism and the pragmatic maxim, which states: "Consider the practical effects of the objects of your conception. Then, your conception of those effects is the whole of your conception of the object".

I thought that it might be interesting to generalize this to mathematics, with some alterations.

So, here is my question:

"Let B be the set of all implications of a proposition $a$. Then there exists a function such that $f(a)=B-a.$  Is this function injective?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathsf{Prop}$ with $\land$, $\lor$, $\lnot$ forms a boolean lattice, and the ordering is given by $x \leq y \iff$ $x \to y$.

Then asking if a propostion $a$ is determined by $\{ b \neq a ~|~ a \to b \}$ is asking if $a$ is determined by $\{ b > a \}$.

This is not true, though. For instance consider the lattice with four elements

[image: lattice]

Then $a$ and $\lnot a$ are both sent to $\{ T \}$ by your function, so it is not injective in general.

If we look at $\{b \geq a \}$ instead, which is your function but without removing $a$ from the set, we recover injectivity (for instance, by the Yoneda Lemma).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: +1. At the same time, there are some theories relative to which the result *does* hold - e.g. first-order Peano arithmetic or ZFC.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you elaborate on the proof of that?

Comment: @JohnClever See e.g. the first part of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744398/given-any-incomplete-theory-and-an-unprovable-sentence-varphi-are-there-alwa/3744456#3744456) (that proves a particular "downward-density" result, but the same argument gives the more general result in my comment).

Comment: Thank you, this looks helpful, and gives me another reason to get into algebraic logic.

Comment: @JohnClever - If this answered your question, you should mark it as such so that other users know how to spend their time ^_^